# Passing values from controller into javascript in mvc5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a mvc view which needs to show the twitter feeds. So i have the code generated from twitter in my view. This works fine.

To extend this i want to make this a little dynamic. ie i want to hardcoded `data-widget-id="3831079557xxxx"` to a value from a database table.

Below is the javascript generated by twitter to embed the tweets

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/xxxxx" 
          data-widget-id="3831079557xxxx">Tweets by xxxx</a>
              <script>!function (d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https'; if (!d.getElementById(id)) { js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); } }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");</script>



                </div>
            </div>
```

View Model:

```
public class homeViewModel
{
    public List<news> newsA { get; set; }

    public List<Rss> feeds { get; set; }

    public List<HomepageSetting> hps { get; set; }

}
```

Model: This is the class from which i can get the twitter id

```
public partial class HomepageSetting
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        //other properties
        public string Twitter { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        homeViewModel hvm = new homeViewModel();
        var data = (from p in db.HomepageSetting where p.ProfileID == Cuser.ProfileId select p);
                hvm.hps= data.ToList();
     return View(hvm);
     }
```

Comment: Unclear way to ask. I think if you want to get answer need more description about your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the controller Index method you can use the ViewData Dictionary to pass the id to the view:

```
ViewData["id"] = data.id //for example.
```

In the view, you can use the `ViewData["id"]` entry to assign it to data-widget-id attribute.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/xxxxx" 
          data-widget-id="<%: ViewData["id"] %>">Tweets by xxxx</a>
```

Good Luck

Comment: You probably want to use data-widget-id=@ViewData["id"]

Comment: It depend actually on the view engine used. The solution i wrote is for the ASPX engine. Your solution is for Razor engine. @Prady

Answer (score 1):

You can use Razor Framework and have in the javascript

```
@foreach (var myItem in Request.ServerVariables)
{
    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/xxxxx" 
          data-widget-id="3831079557@myItem ">Tweets by xxxx</a>
}
```

I cannot give you more explaining code, because this is something I was working on MVC4. I am no longer working with the Microsoft Framework sothe code will not be fully functional.

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg606533%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) too for more information in Razor Framework.

Comment: For example, for `Request.ServerVariables` you can load your model with a name in the top of your view, and then call it in the foreach loop.